# Pass a TXT file as stopword list in Scala

Tags: scala, stop-words

I am using the stanford Topic modelling toolbox (TMT) http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/tmt/tmt-0.4/, and I want to prepare my text data set. 
I have a txt file of stopwords.

However,

```
TermStopListFilter()
```

Which filters out stop words from my CSV data set, only accepts a list within the script, such as:

```
TermStopListFilter(List("positively","scrumptious"))
```

How do I import my stopwords.txt file and use it as my stopword list?

A full snipet of the code I use:

```
val source = CSVFile("filtered.csv"); 

val text = {
  source ~>                              
  Column(1) ~>                           
  TokenizeWith(tokenizer) ~>             
  TermCounter() ~>                       
  TermMinimumDocumentCountFilter(100) ~>   
  TermStopListFilter(TXTFile("stopwords.txt"))  
  TermDynamicStopListFilter(10) ~>       
  DocumentMinimumLengthFilter(5)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, if your stopwords are "," separated you can try this:

```
 . 
 .
      TermStopListFilter(Source("stopwords.txt").getLines().map(_.split(",")).toList) 
 .
 .
```

If your stopwords in stopwords.txt are delimited by some other char, change it in  `split(",")` accordingly and most likely you should remove line: `TermStopListFilter(List("positively","scrumptious"))`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. My data to analyse is in filtered.csv, and my stopword list is in stopwords.txt

Won't this code think my stopword list is filtered.csv when the stopwords I need are actually in stopwords.txt ?

Comment: aaa I see, give me a minute- I'll change the answer